# How do filter date time column according to time ranges specified in two column?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, time, multiple-columns

In one excel File that I have filtered-eda data, I want to filter such data according to my second excel file by using two columns; StartTime and EndTime; as a time range

(time column types in two excel datetime64[ns])

you can see my two excel files at picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMo9B.png)

My code is

```
df1 =  pd.read_excel(filename_1)`
df2 = pd.read_excel(filename_2, usecols= "A,C")
df3 = df1[df1['BinaryLabels'] == 1]
df2 = df2[(df3["StartTime"] <= df2.Time) & (df2.Time <= df3["EndTime"])]
print(df2)
```

and get error as :ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

How can I solve it?

Thanks for advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If geenral `DataFrame`s with different number of rows you have to [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with cross join before filtering:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(filename_1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(filename_2, usecols= "A,C")
df3 = df1[df1['BinaryLabels'] == 1]

df = df2.assign(a=1).merge(df3.assign(a=1), on='a', how='outer')
df = df[(df["StartTime"] <= df.Time) & (df.Time <= df["EndTime"])]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, But it gives error as below;   MemoryError: Unable to allocate 203. MiB for an array with shape (1, 26627139) and data type float64

Comment: hi @jezrael can you look at my other question about correlation between time series, I think you have an idea about that https://stackoverflow.com/q/60182894/12746012