# How do find correlation between time events and time series data in python?

Tags: python, time

I have two different excel files. One of them is including time series data (268943 accident time rows) as below

The other file is value of 14 workers measured daily from 8 to 17 and during 4 months(all data merged in one file)

I am trying to understand correlation between accident times and  values (hourly from 8 to 17 per one hour and daily from Monday to Friday and monthly)

Which statistical method is fit(Normalized Auto or cross correlation) and how can I do that?
Generally, in the questions, the correlation analysis are performed between two time series based values, but I think this is a little bit different. Also, here times are different.

Thank your advance..

Comment: Hello I will try answer here. The Datetime columns don't match. You should merge everything into a single dataframe, create a code to groupby and perform the correlation. However you can't apply a correlation unless you are wishing to ignore the year-month-day of the tests, and simply check by hour.

Comment: thank you @CeliusStingher, actually, in the other question I put df1 as counted the accident numbers and test the correlation between BSL, but actually, I wan to get hour by hour correlation,

Comment: I doubt this can be done, you are taking different time intervals. How can I match  2010-01-01 at 17hs with  2020-01-25 at 17hs? Furthermore, size is inconsistent between dataframes.

Comment: @CeliusStingher You think there is no way to see the correlation between accident numbers and BSL values for given interval? I hope there should be a solution:)

Comment: The statistics for this might get a bit tricky ... I don't think a simple correlation coefficient would be very meaningful, and it seems you only have BSL for positive occurrences of accidents (BSL is unobserved when accidents don't happen). You may want to consider getting this question moved to CrossValidated.

Comment: @rbatt thanks for your comment, actually, the main target of this project is to observe how BSL values changes when the accident occurrance time. The accident time received for last 8 years and we measured BSL independent of accident times. I think correlation tests maybe CrossValidated give me relation between the accidents and BSL values hourly. For example, the number of accidents and BSL values both increase between 13-14. I want to show relation statistically.Now, I am investigating CrossValidation test

Comment: @CeliusStingher I think your first answer is feasible, but how can I ignore yy-mm-dd? Then I can use auto correlation I think

Answer (score 2):

I think the accident times and the bloodsugar levels are not coming from the same source, and so I think it is not possible to draw a correlation between these two separate datasets. If you would like to assume that the blood sugar levels of all 14 workers reflect that of the workers accident dataset, that is a different story. But what if those who had accidents had a significantly different blood sugar level profile than the rest, and what if your tiny dataset of 14 workers does not comprise such examples? I think the best you may do is to graph the blood sugar level of your 14 worker dataset and also similarly analyze the accident dataset separately, and try to see visually whether there is any correlation here.

Comment: perhaps you may use facebook prophet tool to visualize these time series easily.